# Why do I get a small values with InceptionV3 ? how to set a threshold to detect the present classes in the image?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using InceptionV3 after fine tuning it to my own data set for a multi class multi label classification problem I made the most important changes like softmax to sigmoid and I am using this loss function

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

but when I predict using the generated model I get a small values like this [  2.74303748e-04   7.97736086e-03   2.44359515e-04   7.09630767e-05
   5.43296163e-04   4.08404367e-03   3.28547925e-01   1.05091414e-04
   1.80469989e-03   2.85170972e-03   1.44978316e-04   7.78235449e-03
   1.72435939e-02   1.55413849e-02   3.82270187e-01   1.06311939e-03
   2.70067930e-01   6.08937175e-04   7.47230020e-04   1.07850268e-04]
the source code is this :(can it be my validation set ?)

```
import keras
import os
import sys
import glob
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from keras import __version__
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, 
preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD


IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT = 299, 299 #fixed size for InceptionV3
NB_EPOCHS = 3
BAT_SIZE = 32
FC_SIZE = 1024
NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE = 172


def get_nb_files(directory):
   """Get number of files by searching directory recursively"""
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    return 0
  cnt = 0
  for r, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
      cnt += len(glob.glob(os.path.join(r, dr + "/*")))
  return cnt


def setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model):
  """Freeze all layers and compile the model"""
  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
  #model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
#metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

def add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes):
  """Add last layer to the convnet
  Args:
    base_model: keras model excluding top
    nb_classes: # of classes
  Returns:
        new keras model with last layer
  """
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dense(FC_SIZE, activation='relu')(x) #new FC layer, random init
  predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x) 

  model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
  return model


def setup_to_finetune(model):
  """Freeze the bottom NB_IV3_LAYERS and retrain the remaining top 
     layers.
  note: NB_IV3_LAYERS corresponds to the top 2 inception blocks in the 
  inceptionv3 arch
  Args:
    model: keras model
  """
  for layer in model.layers[:NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE]:
     layer.trainable = False
  for layer in model.layers[NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE:]:
     layer.trainable = True

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy']) 

def train(args):
  """Use transfer learning and fine-tuning to train a network on a new 
  dataset"""
  nb_train_samples = get_nb_files(args.train_dir)
  nb_classes = len(glob.glob(args.train_dir + "/*"))
  nb_val_samples = get_nb_files(args.val_dir)
  nb_epoch = int(args.nb_epoch)
  batch_size = int(args.batch_size)

  # data prep
  train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
   preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
   rotation_range=30,
   width_shift_range=0.2,
   height_shift_range=0.2,
   shear_range=0.2,
   zoom_range=0.2,
   horizontal_flip=True
  )
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True
  )

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    args.train_dir,
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
  )

  validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    args.val_dir,
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
  )

  # setup model
  base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False) 
  #include_top=False excludes final FC layer
  model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes)

  # transfer learning
  setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model)

  history_tl = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_val_samples,
    class_weight='auto')

  # fine-tuning
  setup_to_finetune(model)

  history_ft = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_val_samples,
    class_weight='auto')

  model.save(args.output_model_file)

  if args.plot:
    plot_training(history_ft)


def plot_training(history):
  acc = history.history['acc']
  val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
  loss = history.history['loss']
  val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
  epochs = range(len(acc))

  plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r.')
  plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r')
  plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')

  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r.')
  plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r-')
  plt.title('Training and validation loss')
  plt.show()


if __name__=="__main__":
  a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  a.add_argument("--train_dir")
  a.add_argument("--val_dir")
  a.add_argument("--nb_epoch", default=NB_EPOCHS)
  a.add_argument("--batch_size", default=BAT_SIZE)
  a.add_argument("--output_model_file", default="inceptionv3-ft.model")
  a.add_argument("--plot", action="store_true")

  args = a.parse_args()
  if args.train_dir is None or args.val_dir is None:
    a.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

  if (not os.path.exists(args.train_dir)) or (not 
   os.path.exists(args.val_dir)):
   print("directories do not exist")
   sys.exit(1)

  train(args)
```

Comment: And what is the question? Getting small values is not a problem at all, its expected as the output are probabilities.

Comment: Matias Valdenegro : my question is referring to what I red online they should be between 0 and 1 yes they are but not as tiny as this I expected a sample like this for example [0.6 , 0.7 0.4 ....] so I can set my threshold to 0.5

Comment: You are just getting confused by scientific notation, look at the numbers I get when I format your probabilities to 2 significant figures: ['0.00', '0.01', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.33', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.01', '0.02', '0.02', '0.38', '0.00', '0.27', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00']

Comment: Mathias Valdenegro I know what you mean but some values should be >0.5(the present classes ) and some others should be <0.5( the non present classes ) and here the highest values like 0.33 and 0.37 .. are for the present classes (that is true) but they should be >0.5 no?

Comment: For that you need to properly train the neural network, get a low loss value for both training and validation sets. Only after that you should look at the output and see if they make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You answer your own question. This is the reason.

> I made the most important changes like softmax to sigmoid

[Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) maps the input to the range [0, 1]. Hence the output values of the network are just the outputs of this function and are not class probabilities. Maximum value from the nodes will give you the neuron that has the maximum output and hence the present class.

When you say

> but some values should be >0.5(the present classes ) and some others should be <0.5( the non present classes )

in the comments, you are referring to the probability of >0.5 of the present class. What you require for class probabilities is the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function).

Therefore replacing your last sigmoid layer with a softmax layer will get you what you think you should be observing.